# Remove rows with small values

Tags: r, dataframe

I know how to remove rows from a data frame if the values are 0 or NA in R.

```
   df2 <- df[rowSums(df[, -(1:2)]) > 0, ]
```

I want to instead remove any row where all the values are between 0 and 1 (these are the lowly expressed genes).

Below is my data (df)

```
gene    Entrez.ID   PM100_Z1_1_RNA  PM117_Z10_1_Case_RNASeq  PM117_Z1_1_Case_RNASeq
A1BG    1   7.1886  0.3574  0.6062
A1BG-AS1    503538  1.9383  1.4106  0.3262
A1CF    29974   3.00E-04    0.0032  0.0431
A2M 2   126.106 41.165  7.6365
A2M-AS1 144571  1.5309  0.7507  0.2549
A2ML1   144568  0.1075  0.5919  1.957
A2MP1   3   0.1319  0.1094  0.889
A3GALT2 127550  0.0842  0.0042  0.0536
A4GALT  53947   27.2484 5.3346  3.2796
A4GNT   51146   0.0375  0.0341  0.0618
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are using `rowSums(dat)`, which sums up the values in the row. However, you actually want to count the number of values that exceed 1, which can be accomplished with `rowSums(dat > 1)`, aka the row sums of a logical matrix storing whether each value exceeds 1. Then you can limit to rows with at least one value exceeding 1 with:

```
dat[rowSums(dat[,-(1:2)] > 1) > 0,]
#       gene Entrez.ID PM100_Z1_1_RNA PM117_Z10_1_Case_RNASeq PM117_Z1_1_Case_RNASeq
# 1     A1BG         1         7.1886                  0.3574                 0.6062
# 2 A1BG-AS1    503538         1.9383                  1.4106                 0.3262
# 4      A2M         2       126.1060                 41.1650                 7.6365
# 5  A2M-AS1    144571         1.5309                  0.7507                 0.2549
# 6    A2ML1    144568         0.1075                  0.5919                 1.9570
# 9   A4GALT     53947        27.2484                  5.3346                 3.2796
```